# create XCFramework with other dependency by cocoapods，push repo to cocoapods failed

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a private XCFramework which dependency other SDK SnapKit by cocoapods. Create the XCFramework successfully，but when I push it to cocoapods failed. The failed info is：

```
 ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'SnapKit'
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_$s7SnapKit15ConstraintMakerC3topAA0cD10ExtendableCvgTj", referenced from:
          _$s12MUIEmptyView0A12SubTitleItemC08generateB033_27F9F4727AFD9E91600B881F5A35D154LLyyFy7SnapKit15ConstraintMakerCXEfU_ in MUIEmptyView(MUIEmptySubTitleItem.o)
          _$s12MUIEmptyView0A9TitleItemC08generateB033_EE0DD1A78CCCF878CA42342F65843B6ALLyyFy7SnapKit15ConstraintMakerCXEfU_ in MUIEmptyView(MUIEmptyTitleItem.o)
          ...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My podspec is:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyFramework"
  s.version      = "1.0.1"
  s.summary      = "MyFramework的一个简单示范工程."
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   MyFramework的一个简单示范工程示范工程的长描述.
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "xxx"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author             = { "xxx" => "xxx" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "12.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "xxx", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.swift_versions = ['5.0']
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME) $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)' }
  s.default_subspecs = 'Core'
  s.subspec 'Core' do |core|
    core.dependency 'SnapKit'
    core.vendored_frameworks = "#{s.name}.xcframework"
    core.resource_bundles = {
      "#{s.name}" => ["#{s.name}/Resources/**/*"]
    }
  end
end
```

Any alternate approach?

I got XCFramework successfully, but I do not have idea to solve this problem.